# react facing error when want to get specific value from back-end

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am trying to get value from the back-end, it shows totally fine and grabs all the properties in the console, but when I want to access a particular value it shows an error, but sometimes it's working I have tried with useEffect dependencies but still same,
the error is:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'eventName')
example JSON format:

0:{
eventFeeStudent: "34"
eventName: "New event"
eventNotificationsDate: "2022-05-23T18:00:00.000Z"
}

here it's working fine but when want to catch any specific key pair like eventName I am getting error.

```
const EventEditNavbar = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});
  console.log(userInfo);
  console.log(user);
  // console.log(userInfo[0].eventName);
  const eventName = userInfo[0].eventName;




  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user || !user.email) return
    const uri = `http://localhost:5000/findevents/?userEmail=${user.email}`;
    fetch(uri)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setUserInfo(data));
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="eventEdit_nav">
        <div className="eventEdit_nav_right">
          <Link to={`/festivals/${eventName}`}>View</Link>
          <Link to="/">Edit</Link>
          <Link to="">Manage</Link>
          <Link to="">Marketing</Link>
        </div>
        <div className="eventEdit_nav_left">
          <Link to="">Save</Link>
          <Link to="">List Event</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default EventEditNavbar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind whenever an object's property is `undefined` accessing its child will throw an uncaught error, which means there is nothing beneath an undefined property.

In your case, you are initiating the `userInfo` with an empty object (`{}`), so the `userInfo[0]` in the first place (when there are no data fetched from the server) will be `undefined` and it will throw an error when you try to access its child. To solve this you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), whenever you try something like this.

So doing this will solve your issue:

```js
const eventName = userInfo[0]?.eventName;

/* Whenever userInfo is undefined the eventName will
be set to undefined as well and it will prevent the
application from throwing an error when you try to
access userInfo child */
```